# Angular ui-keydown with multiple handlers

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I have this which is working:

```
ui-keydown="{ 'ctrl-67':'doSomething()'}"
```

but what should I do if I would want for `ctrl-68` some other behavior? for example something like:

```
ui-keydown="{ 'ctrl-67':'doSomething()'; 'ctrl-68':'doSomethingElse()'}"
```

This doesn't work, because of duplicate attribute:

```
ui-keydown="{ 'ctrl-67':'doSomething()'}" ui-keydown="{'ctrl-68':'doSomethingElse()'}"
```

What I managed to make work is\

```
ui-keydown="{ 'ctrl-67':'doSomething()'}" ui-keyup="{'ctrl-68':'doSomethingElse()'}"
```

but this is not good because I will need other keys too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add more key bindings in the same object:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/plantface/g5urc5s9/)

```
<input type="text" ui-keydown="{ 'enter': 'doCtrl.doFoo()', 'backspace': 'doCtrl.doBar()' }">
```

Comment: great, thanks! I didn't know the syntax. I was trying ";" instead of ","

Comment: @bokkie `var obj = {}` is an implicit object constructor (or object literal) and allows you to [declaratively define an object](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_definition.asp).